# Converting Summation from MuPAD to Matlab Function

Tags: matlab, function, equation, mupad

I am trying to convert the following summation into a Matlab function through MuPAD:

[image: double sum equation]

This is what I have done so far...

1. In Matlab, enter `notebook_handle = mupad;`
2. In MuPAD I had formulated the above equation to be : `C = sum(sum(((Xkit)*#P1k), #k=#1..#D), #i=#1..#t-1)`
   Note: I am equating the summation to a variable C
3. Equate the above expression in MuPAD
4. In Matlab Command window enter : `C = getVar(notebook_handle,'C')`

I am closely following the documentation ([Create MATLAB Functions from MuPAD Expressions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/create-matlab-functions-from-mupad-expressions.html)). I am able to formulate the example given easily but not the one I am trying to solve.

My guess is that there is something wrong with Step 2?

Comment: Also, what version of Matlab are you using? MuPAD is constantly changing.